# Function lastRec - how does it work exactly?

Tags: vba, function, range

The function below is supposed to return the row within a range with the last entry.
As far as I can see it the function works, but I'm wondering what `myRange(myRange.Count).Row` and `myRange(1)` is supposed to mean?
Thanks for your help!

```
Public Function lastRec(myRange As range, myDate As Date)
    For x = myRange(myRange.Count).Row To myRange(1).Row Step -1
        If CDate(Left(Cells(x, myRange.Column), 10)) = myDate Then
            lastRec = x
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next x
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `lastRec()` function actually returns the row of the first cell in `myRange` whose value first 10 characters matches the passed `myDate`

it works if `myRange` is a 1-columned range

`myRange(myRange.Count).Row` returns the row index of the last cell in `myRange`

`myRange(1).Row` returns the row index of the first cell in `myRange`

Comment: Wouldn't that return the last cell in `myRange` as it's working backwards with `Step -1`.  It will also fail if the cell is empty, or the first 10 characters can't be coerced into a date or if you have a different sheet selected other than that specified in `myRange` (the `Cells` command will look at the active sheet).

Answer (score 0):

`Range.Count` returns a Long value that represents the number of objects in the collection, as `range.row` returns the number of the first row of the first area in the range.

`range(1)` is where 1 names the range, to return a Range object that represents a single cell or a range of cells.